# Cannot install TensorFlow on Mac M1. Running into error during install

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

I am fairly new to programming, i am trying to install tensorflow on my machine. My Macbook has the M1 chip which apparently makes life hard when you want tensorflow.
I follwed along with a guy on youtube, and i am stuck at the very last step. I have an anaconda virtual environment set up, it even said it was successful when i ran this install file `install_venv.sh` (From MacOS tensorflow/github page...https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/releases)

however when i then run `import tensorflow as tf` it raises this error (sorry for the length, included the entire error so i dont miss anything) Someone please help and maybe teach me why this is happening.

I've been trying to get tensorflow working for hours!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jacobholmes/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_opencv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/jacobholmes/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_opencv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/jacobholmes/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_opencv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/jacobholmes/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_opencv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jacobholmes/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_opencv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "/Users/jacobholmes/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_opencv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Users/jacobholmes/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_opencv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jacobholmes/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_opencv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/jacobholmes/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_opencv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/jacobholmes/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_opencv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/jacobholmes/opt/anaconda3/envs/test_opencv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
>>> /Users/jacobholmes/Downloads/tensorflow_macos/ins
```

Comment: It seems that you somehow installed the TensorFlow for a different architecture (likely x86_64).

Comment: Did you tried as discussed [here](https://naturale0.github.io/2021/01/29/setting-up-m1-mac-for-both-tensorflow-and-pytorch) for Setting up M1 Mac for TensorFlow? It may useful. Thanks!